# Dept. wise Prompted link!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, promoted-links

I need to create a page with tiles (linked with URLs of internal Department web-apps), concern is that only the related tiles should be display to the user (HR tiles to HR dept. user and Finance Tiles to Finance dept. user).

Planing to use Prompted link app to solve the "Tiles" purpose,  but not sure how to achieve that "dept. wise display" functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most obvious solution would be to set unique permissions on items in promoted links list. Of course you should create groups for HR, Finance, etc. You can also use AD groups for assigning permissions.

Usually setting granular permissions isn't recommended for performance and manageability reasons. But I assume only a couple of items will be created on this list, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I thought of it first but the problem is that the default TILE view in Prompted Link app would not allow user to modify the view (so I can't filter the items, based of groups)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Thats why I dodn't suggest to modify the view. If you set unique permissions on item level, users will only see items they have access to, regardless of view filters. This [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-9d13e7df-a770-4646-91ab-e3c117fcef45?CorrelationId=689ed441-fa1b-4ee3-8409-dbb91d856f60&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm10) describes how to modify permissions.